# C++ Word Automation problem export chart or sheet in a workbook to Image

Tags: c++, ms-word, word-automation

I need to insert a chart as an image programmatically in Word. Before being able to do that I need to convert a chart or a sheet (only containing a chart) of an excel workbook automatically. I've recorded a macro and got to know that following VBA code is doing that:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObject(1).Chart.Export "C:\ path .......jpg"
```

Another way would be using SaveAs() but I found no sample code.

How can this be done in C++? I could not find this for C++

I would really appreciate any help on this matter!

Thanks in advance.

Chris

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start with the Word COM library. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178749/EN-US for an example on excel. it's the same for word.